# Why is static ddl not allowed in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In an Oracle PL/SQL block, why is dynamic sql allowed

```
begin
    execute immediate 'drop table table_name';
end;
```

but static is not?

```
begin
    drop table table_name;
end;
```

I hope the answer is more insightful than "because that's how the language works".

Comment: Without a reference to the thinking of the PL/SQL design team, I do not think we can **know** why PL/SQL does not allow static DDL. We can only discuss the pluses and minuses of the approach and there won't be an answer that is **the** answer.

Comment: I think the answers given so far prove this question is answerable, supported by facts - and probably constructive as well.

Comment: Jeffrey Kemp is correct, the approved answer shows that this question should not have been closed - as so many others on the site, sadly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is PL/SQL does not support dynamic polymorphism. it only supports static polymorphism because

All PL/SQL generats a "DIANA" -> Descriptive Intermediate Attributed Notation for Ada , a tree-structured intermediate language. DIANA is used internally by compilers.

At compile time, PL/SQL source code is translated into system code and generates corresponding DIANA. Now think if there were a DDL statement like create table statement which at the compile time does not exists it will be created after running the program. how would your PL/SQL engine generate a DIANA then ????

The DIANA is plays an important role in PL/SQL to check/validate that the sub program. this is required because as we know that a sub-program can use database objects such as Tables,Views,Synonyms or other stored procs. it could be possible that the the objects may have changed/removed/droped when next time you run the program. For ex : some one might have droped the table, the stored proc or function singnature may have changed.

Thats why generally PL/SQL is used to manipulate the data within database structure, but not to manipulate those structures.

but there are ways to manipulate using dynamic SQL and DBMS_SQL package but theses methodlogy are again should be used cautiously. For example if you are creating a Table you should check first if this table is already exists or not using data dictionary views.

Comment: '_DDL statement like create table statement which at the compile time does not exists_'. but why are DDL statements not part of compile time?

Answer (score 3):

Probably because otherwise some code would be like:

```
  begin
    create table tmp (n number);
    insert into tmp values (1);
  end;
```

And we would expect the compiler to *know* that at time of the insert, the table exists. The compilation of the block would me much more difficult. Here it is a very simple case, but we can easily imagine some conditional branching, and complex blabla.

But, since we need to put the DDL in an execute immediate block, the limitation maybe somehow easier to understand.

Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Before execution/compilation, oracle checks all access permissions,validity and dependencies of all schema objects like tables,views,[stored procs](https://www.wowdbase.com/2020/04/plsql-stored-procedure-oracle-database.html) etc referenced inside a pl/sql block. But problem with DDL statement is that it 
can create, alter or drop schema object and as a result, it can change the object dependencies.So it is possible that we are referring one object which has been dropped using DDL. To prevent such situation I guess plsql block does not allow direct DDL statement.
But we can still include DDL in PL/SQL block using Dynamic query. As in this case the actual query is not known until run-time, basically we can hide the DDL statement in the form of Dynamic SQL and include DDL inside PL/SQL block.

You can refer my blog to understand the concept with example:
[Why oracle does not allow direct DDL statements inside the procedure (PLSQL BLOCK)](https://www.wowdbase.com/2020/04/why-oracle-doesnt-allow-direct-ddl.html)

Comment: When linking to your own blog, you need to be sure to disclose that it is your article. I’ve noticed you’ve made two posts this week linking to articles you wrote without disclosing that fact. That can be interpreted as spam. Please update your answers to disclose your affiliation.

Comment: please let me know if it is fine now.

Comment: Yes, much better—thank you. For reference, the Help Center has a good guide on ["How to not be a spammer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) which discusses the rules around self-promotion. In short, as long as you are actually including the solution in your answer, using the link to support your solution, and disclosing your affiliation, and not blanketing the site with such answers, you should be good. With this edit, you seem to be staying within those guidelines.